# SQL Server - PIVOT query return NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have this data.

[image]

I want Pivot data for each IndemnityId use distinct columns from "TereceniIznosColumnName" and put data from "TereceniIznosValue".

When I Execute this query:

```
        SELECT 
        *
     FROM 
     (
        SELECT
        IndemnityId
        ,TereceniIznosColumnName 
        ,TereceniIznosValue
        from #tmpData 

     ) x
     pivot 
     (
        SUM(TereceniIznosValue)
        FOR TereceniIznosColumnName
        IN  ([TereceniIznos1],[TereceniIznos2],[TereceniIznos3],[TereceniIznos4],[TereceniIznos5],[TereceniIznos6],[TereceniIznos7],[TereceniIznos8],[TereceniIznos9],[TereceniIznos10])
     ) p
```

I get NULL Values

[image]

Did I miss some data types or what?

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use tabular text.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your `TereceniIznosColumnName` values contain quotes so that result is `NULL`, I would use condition aggregate function which can judge the quotes.

```
SELECT IndemnityId,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TereceniIznosColumnName = '[TereceniIznos1]' THEN TereceniIznosValue ELSE 0 END) TereceniIznos1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TereceniIznosColumnName = '[TereceniIznos2]' THEN TereceniIznosValue ELSE 0 END) TereceniIznos2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TereceniIznosColumnName = '[TereceniIznos3]' THEN TereceniIznosValue ELSE 0 END) TereceniIznos3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TereceniIznosColumnName = '[TereceniIznos4]' THEN TereceniIznosValue ELSE 0 END) TereceniIznos4,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TereceniIznosColumnName = '[TereceniIznos5]' THEN TereceniIznosValue ELSE 0 END) TereceniIznos5,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TereceniIznosColumnName = '[TereceniIznos6]' THEN TereceniIznosValue ELSE 0 END) TereceniIznos6,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TereceniIznosColumnName = '[TereceniIznos7]' THEN TereceniIznosValue ELSE 0 END) TereceniIznos7,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TereceniIznosColumnName = '[TereceniIznos8]' THEN TereceniIznosValue ELSE 0 END) TereceniIznos8,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TereceniIznosColumnName = '[TereceniIznos9]' THEN TereceniIznosValue ELSE 0 END) TereceniIznos9,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TereceniIznosColumnName = '[TereceniIznos10]' THEN TereceniIznosValue ELSE 0 END) TereceniIznos10
FROM #tmpData 
GROUP BY IndemnityId
```

Comment: Column contains qoutes and also I have ten columns because this is what was executed from dynamic query.